# statusBar color is a different color to my colorPrimaryDark

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

Here's my colors.xml, where the `colorPrimaryDark` is orange:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#ffbf80</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
</resources>
```

My statusBar is still black, even though i've set an orange color to my `colorPrimaryDark`. Why is this?

Here's my styles.xml:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:colorForeground">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.zorgan.app" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" >
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

the dark action bar is the culprit, try setting no action bar instead.`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">`

bare in mind, you will ofto make a custom toolbar.

Please follow this tutorial for more guidance
http://www.android4devs.com/2014/12/how-to-make-material-design-app.html

also switch this `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" >` to `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`

Comment: this way your manifest will always reference your styled custom themes.

Answer (score 0):

use your theme in your application tag.

```
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```